# Differential Operator

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, differentiation, calculus

I am trying to understand the following expression
\begin{eqnarray}
e^{-ik.x}D_{\mu}D^{\mu}e^{ik.x} & = & e^{-ik.x}(i\partial_{\mu}+A_{\mu})(i\partial^{\mu}+A^{\mu})e^{ik.x}\\
& = & e^{-ik.x}(i\partial_{\mu}+A_{\mu})(-e^{ik.x}k^{\mu}+e^{ik.x}\boxed{i\partial_{\mu}}+e^{ik.x}A_{\mu})
\end{eqnarray}
The thing i don't understand the origin on the term inside the box. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes:
$$
\partial_\mu \mathrm e^{ikx}=ik_\mu\mathrm e^{ikx}+\mathrm e^{ikx}\partial_\mu
$$
because the differential operator acts on a test function (i.e., product rule).

Comment: If i understand you then i must consider $ik_{\mu}e^{ikx}+e^{ikx}\partial_{\mu}$ acting on some test function say ^{\psi(x)} to get the result. Thank you!

Comment: yes, that's it :-)